# How does allowing breaking grabs with keyboard actions pose a security risk?

Tags: linux

While modifying the Gnome Tweak Tool I saw the following option which states that allowing breaking grabs with keyboard actions poses a security risk.

[image]

How can it be a security risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://who-t.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/xkb-breaking-grabs-cve-2012-0064.html):

> The bug allows users to work around screen locking (e.g.
>   gnome-screensaver) by hitting Control+Alt+keypad multiply or
>   Control+Alt+keypad divide. This terminates the input grab the
>   screensaver has and thus allows a user to interact with the desktop,
>   skipping the password entry.

Therefore enabling this feature will allow the screensaver lock to be bypassed.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a security risk because an unwanted application may use that for additional control of the KB functions.

The confirmed security risk is in the case of wireless KB connectivity, as this can be used for eavesdropping, and if such a thing happens it may be hard to debug/identify.